# Java: Cannot access images in resources

Tags: java, url, resources, imageicon

I've been trying to export my project as a Runnable Jar, but my resources would not load because I was directly trying to access the image from my project's path. For example:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("resources/icon.png");
```

This would work when I ran the project from Eclipse itself, but I noticed that the images were not being included in the jar file. So after researching, I found out that I need to create source folders and put the images/text files inside them, and then use getClass().getResource() in order to access them. However, when I do this, the URL is always returned as null.

For reference, this is what my project explorer looks like:

```
Test
---src

---resources
   ---icon.png

---config
   ---file.ini
```

And here is the code that is giving me a NullPointerException when trying to access icon.png:

```
ImageIcon icon = getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.png");
```

Alternatively, I have also tried:

```
ImageIcon icon = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/icon.png");
```

But that also ends up in a NullPointerException. I have checked many solutions online but none of them have seemed to work for me. Please note that I also need to be able to access the .ini file, so a solution that only works for images won't fully solve my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: when packaged as a jar, where is icon.png ? Could you post the jar structure too ?

Comment: Resources needs to go as a folder under /src

Comment: Try `"/icon.png"` - or look with 7zip, WinZip or such in the jar for the path. Without the leading `/` the path would be relative to the package path of the class on which you do getResource.

Comment: Thanks Joop and basic, both of your solutions worked for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure needs to be:

```
TEST
   -SRC
     -Resources
       -icon.png
```

The way your code is right now is there is no image because your code is referencing /src/resources not test/resources

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me actually. When I try to add a source folder inside src, it automatically puts it outside, and if I try to cut/paste it, it turns it into a package. I tried it with the package and it still seemed to give a NullPointerException, but Joop's answer worked for me.

EDIT: Nevermind, I compiled it again and it started working? Thanks!

Comment: To add: in order for this solution to work, I had to use "/icon.png" as the URL.
EDIT: Just found out that this only works in Eclipse, and when I exported it as a Runnable Jar, it didn't work. However, using Joop's solution with the way my project was set up before worked even after exporting.